# Automatically Cancel Spring Task on Exception

Tags: spring, exception, scheduled-tasks

I have a Spring Task defined on in spring app context xml:

```
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="1"/>

<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="MyClass" method="myMethod" fixed-delay="3000"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

So, how can I implement to stop further execution of the tasks in case of an Exception, either in xml or in code by catching the Exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is solvable using `scheduled-tasks`, may be wrong of course.

There's an alternative though, config:

```
<task:annotation-driven scheduler="scheduler"  />

<bean id="scheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler">
    <property name="poolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="errorHandler" ref="scheduledTaskErrorHandler" />
</bean>

<bean id="scheduledTaskErrorHandler" class="boo.ScheduledTaskErrorHandler" />
```

And the errorHandler:

```
public class ScheduledTaskErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

@Override
public void handleError(Throwable t) {
        // do something, like shutdown the scheduler
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this (in grails):

`context.'component-scan'('base-package': "sk.dvsk.messagesplitter")`

`myScheduler(org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler) {`
  `'poolSize = 1`
  `errorHandler = ref('splitterTaskErrorHandler')`
 `}`

 `task.'annotation-driven'(myScheduler) `

But there was 2 problems: The error handler wasn't called on exception. And I wasn't abble to shutdown the scheduler (Injected into executor and catcher the exception) by callind shutdown or destroy methods.

Comment: I have no idea about grails, are you sure if something should work with java, it should also with grails? can you check with java?

Comment: These think that work with java should work with groovy also. I tried in a standalone application, where shutdown was working ok, but not the error handler wasn't called when an exception was thrown from scheduled method. (when I called shutdown from scheduled method it wokred as is meant to be here, not in grails :s )

Comment: Ok so the shutdown work if I used resource.xml not resource.groovy. Maybe there is some bug with resource.groovy regarding to tasks.